# Using Nodes in a LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I want to fill up a LinkedList with integers, then do stuff with that LinkedList. What do I have to do to be able to use Nodes, and .next(s) to be able to move through the linkedlist? (end goal of the program is to traverse and remove certain integers based on a criteria)

```
  import java.util.*;

  public class Mary {

public static Mary head; 
public static int counter;

public static int mary(int N, int K) {

    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    list.add(i);

    } 
     //i want to do stuff with nodes and .nexts.. etc here      

    System.out.println(list);
    return N;

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    mary(6,3);

}

}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Good example here: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/linkedlist-in-java-with-example/
Shows you how to add, remove, get, etc.

Comment: what have you tried so far?  we will not do the work for you, but we can help you tweak your code to fix issues

Comment: You need to write your own linked list class, not use the built in one

Answer (score 1):

I guess `Iterator` would be the most suitable in your case.

```
Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    Integer value = it.next();
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

When you insert this part after commented line in your code this will output all numbers in the list.

So if you will need to go through `LinkedList` create an `Iterator` with `iterator()` method and then use its `next()` method to get the value and move to the next element and `hasNext()` to check that there are more elements in the list.